# Find items from the array of strings in array of hashes and proceed with the appropriate hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, find, hash

I have an array of links:

```
array = [link1, link2, link3, link4]
```

and array_of_hashes with two items: :names and :links

```
hash = { :names, :links } e.g.
array_of_hashes = [{ :names => name5, :links => link5}, {:names = name1, :links => link1}, ... ]
```

I want to do something with each pair of hashes (:names :links) from array_of_hashes which including links from the original array of links.

Thus, at final stage I need to find pair of hashes (in my case listed above):

```
{:names => name1, :links => link1}
```

cause link1 are listed in the array with links

**UPD:** Revised data... sorry for missunderstanding. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: Really unclear on what you're trying to achieve - are you attempting to filter the `array_of_hashes` based on whether the `links` value is present in `array`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find names for each link in array from array_of_hashes.

Comment: So, you basically want a copy of `array_of_hashes` but containing *only* the links which are present in `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
# Cleaned up the setup a little
array_of_hashes = [
    {:names => 'name5', :links => 'link5'}, 
    {:names => 'name1', :links => 'link1'}, 
    {:names => 'name9', :links => 'link9'}]

array = ['link5', 'link1']

# This will filter the array
array_of_hashes.select{|x| array.include? x[:links]}
```

This gives the output `=> [{:names=>"name1", :links=>"link1"}]`